# Task vs Void In Terms Of Controller Disposal

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When I use `void` for the controller's return type, I see that controller is disposed before the action is completed and I get the

> "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending."

error.

```
public async void Test(){
    SomeResult result = await GetSomethingAsync();
    int a = result.b;
}
```

But if I use `Task` instead of `void`, controller is disposed after the action completes.

Why is this behavior?

Comment: This might help: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-1-Async-void-is-for-top-level-event-handlers-only

Comment: [`async void` is unnatural](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). [ASP.NET gives you that error as a safety net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, because MVC framework cannot await "void" :)

Action of your controller is not the end of the pipeline in fact it is somewhere in the [middle.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) So when you make a return type of your action as "void" the thread that executes the code exists your "Test" method and starts executing what was after the invocation of it. Since it can't await it it assumes that the action has finished executing and that the framework can "kill" your controller.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ControllerActionInvoker.cs#L325) you'll find that these two cases are executed in a different way. In particular the one that returns "void" is not awaited. I would recommend having the async/await flow all way, instead of returning "void".

Is there a reason you want to have a return type of "void"?

Comment: I don't actually have a special reason for having the return type as void. But now that I think of it in the light of your answer, what can be a practical reason to make the return type of the asyc action void if it is ignored anyway? Is there a reason why the framework allows it?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason, it is needed to support async/await for the event handlers. Those methods need to have a specific signature defined by a delegate and a lot of them have "void" as the return type. So the framework team decision was to allow async/await on "void" for that.